# How to define vue routers with dynamic child routes?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying something like this

```
{
    path: "/portfolio",
    component: () =>
      import("../common/components/Layout/Layout/Profile/ProfileLayout"),
    meta: { requiresAuth: false },
    children: [
      {
        path: "/:username",
        component: () =>
          import(/*webpackChunkName: "profile"*/ "../modules/Profile/Profile"),
      },
    ],
},
```

But the piece of code is not working while routes without child routes working perfectly

```
{
  path: "/profile/:userName",
  component: () => import("../modules/profile/UserProfile"),
}
```

how can i solve the first piece of code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the prepended slash from the child route path :

```
path: ":username",
```

or try out :

```
path: "user/:username",
```

then you could visit the url like `/portfolio/user/john`

Comment: just a counter question, what's the best solution when a user wants to visit on `/portfolio` path (without any specific user name)?

Comment: that redirects to `ProfileLayout` component which could have links to all profiles

Comment: can you please answer this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67091419/how-to-set-up-vue-cors-for-different-domain-api?noredirect=1#comment118592679_67091419